# OpenTelemetry Lambda Layer Extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, open-telemetry, aws-lambda-layers

Does it usually take time for the Exporter to export the traces? It is configured to export the traces with an authentication. But I'm seeing that the URL for the authentication is being invoked only after not less than 6 minutes after the Lambda function is invoked.

For example, the Lambda Function is invoked at around 11:30 AM. But the URL for the authentication is invoked around 11:38 AM. The URL here is where it will fetch the token to be authenticated. Even if the token is already cached, it is still being invoked after not less than 6 minutes. And causing the events or traces to be dropped.

Here's a sample config:

```yaml
exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: CENTRAL_COLLECTOR:4317
    tls:
      ca_file: /opt/certificate/ca.pem
      cert_file: /opt/certificate/certificate.pem
      key_file: /opt/certificate/private-key.pem
    auth:
      authenticator: oauth2client
```

Is there a delay in the exporter part for it to be exported?

Answer (score 0):

Export is asynchronous process, so it may take a while. Also trace backend may need some processing until you will see trace available.
Real example: Lambda to Lightstep -> whole process needs ~30secs. So I would say 6 minutes is unusual. Your setup and system load is not clear, so under some circumstances it can be normal (e.g. trace backend has slow storage and a lot of traces to process).

Comment: I've got mine working by disabling the `sending_queue` under the `exporters` section. So the traces were coming in less than 1 minute.